# which site template is best for public site in Share Point 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sitetemplate

I have to create a public facing site, surely it will have a admin panel.

which site template is best for public site in Share Point 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Publishing Site` - This is intended for public facing site.

See:

[A preview of the SharePoint Server 2010 site templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/a-preview-of-the-sharepoint-server-2010-site-templates-HA101907564.aspx#_Toc265154600)